# How do you run several commands in docker containers in parallel, then wait for them all to complete?

Tags: docker

In normal bash without docker

```
sleep 30 &
sleep 20 &
sleep 10 &
wait
```

I want to do this inside some docker containers

```
docker exec -d container1 "sleep 30"
docker exec -d container2 "sleep 20"
docker exec -d container3 "sleep 10"
wait
```

However, the wait terminates immediately. I know its possible to use ps -ef to obtain the pids of the running processes and create a polling loop to check when they terminate with kill, but this feels extremely convoluted and unnecessary.

Docker wait doesn't work in my case because the container doesn't stop after running these commands.

Comment: `In normal bash without docker` So just run it in bash in docker the same way.

Comment: @tkausl note that i am using 3 different docker containers

Comment: Can you `docker run` a new container for each command, and then `docker wait` for them all to complete?

Comment: I want to run the commands in containers i already have running in background.

Comment: `wait` only makes sense for things you background using the `&` operator in bash. For something like `docker run -d ...`, the command put itself into the background so bash does know anything about it. If you were to lose the `-d` and use `&` instead it might just work (`docker exec container1 sleep 30 &`, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I start some containers:

```
docker run -d --name container1 fedora34 sleep inf
docker run -d --name container2 fedora34 sleep inf
docker run -d --name container3 fedora34 sleep inf
```

This works just fine for me:

```
docker exec container1 sleep 30 &
docker exec container2 sleep 20 &
docker exec container3 sleep 10 &
wait
```

You can see my complete test [here](https://asciinema.org/a/SJZaFfqeNhsykpZWkTa2WmzmU).

Comment: Your video uses container1 three times, but this solution definitely works. Thanks.

Comment: Haha, sorry about that. Good catch. Glad it helped!